# Express Handlebars append page content to partial page

Tags: express-handlebars

I am new to express-handlebars and finding difficulty in understanding it.

**my layout**

**views**

-layouts

```
 -mainlayout.hbs
```

-partials

```
 -header.hbs(it contains main menu)
 -footer.hbs
 -patialpage.hbs
```

pagecontent.hbs

my main page

`<div>
{{body}}
</div>`

this is my partial page

```
{{>header}}
```

`<div>
     <div>Side Bar Menu</div>
     <div>Page Content Here</div>
 </div>`

```
{{>footer}}
```

this is my content

```
<div>This Content to be append in partial page</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just did in the wrong sequence.
You tried to append the page content to a partial.
In the main layout you define the look of your page.
partials are e.g. parts of this layout (e.g. navbar, footer, ...)

Your main could look like:

```
<div>
{{> header}}
{{body}}
{{> footer}}
</div>
```

this means: on each side the header and the footer partial will be loaded and in between, inside {{body}} there will be the rendered view.

example of a main.handlebars file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>

  {{!-- navbar partial --}}
  {{> _navbar}}

  {{!-- flash messages --}}
  {{> _flashmessages}}

  {{!-- placeholder for rendered views --}}
  {{{body}}}
</body>

</html>
```

then you can render a view based on this main layout.

example with just a text rendered

```js
// Index Route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello world");
  });
});
```

example with the view index.handlebars rendered to the {{body}} part of the page

```js
// Index Route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index');
});
```